# Alternative A hyperlink color in List

Tags: html, css

I have a list like

```
<ul>
      <li>ho <a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li>ho <a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li>ho <a href="#">test</a></li>
      <li>ho <a href="#">test</a></li>
</ul>
```

​and I like to have the links in alternative colors:

following code doesn't work

```
li.a:nth-child(odd) { color:green }
li.a:nth-child(even) { color:red }​
```

Here is the code Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/KqRfe/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expand your selectors to target anchors instead of the list items themselves:

```
li:nth-child(odd) a { 
    color: green;
}

li:nth-child(even) a { 
    color: red;
}​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/KqRfe/2/